# How to rename entries in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I have a dataframe like this

```
df=
a  b  
54 12
54 16
18 3
3  33
```

I want to rename the entries starting from `0` and return something like this:

```
df1=
a  b
0  1
0  2
3  4
4  5
```

Comment: Are those two dataframes connected in any way? Why 'rename' instead of defining a new one?

Comment: they are not connected in anyway. We can use the same name

Comment: so whats wrong with: `df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[54, 54, 18, 3],'b':[12, 16, 3, 33]})` and `df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,3,4],'b':[1,2,4,5]})`? Just to understand the question.

Comment: You may want to give some information HOW you calculate the new data from the old.

Comment: I think I understood the question (see my answer). I could edit it, but I can't think of a good title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can get the list of unique values in your dataframe with:

```
In [1]: pd.Series(df.values.flatten()).unique()
Out[1]: array([54, 12, 16, 18,  3, 33])
```

Let's make it into a series (you'll see why):

```
In [2]: series = pd.Series(pd.Series(df.values.flatten()).unique())
In [3]: series
Out[3]:
    0
0  54
1  12
2  16
3  18
4   3
5  33
```

Now all you need to do is replace the original values with the index of the above series.

---

For a given value, e.g. `16`, here is how you do it:

```
In [4]: series[series==16].index[0]
Out[4]: 
2
```

Now you can apply this to the entire dataframe with a lambda function. The method `applymap` will apply the lambda function to each element separately:

```
In [5]: df.applymap(lambda x: series[series==x].index[0])
Out[5]:
   a  b
0  0  1
1  0  2
2  3  4
3  4  5
```