# sequence of occurrence by multiple catergories

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have tried long long hour to do this but i stuck.
I have many machines produce boxes, each box contained items.
All items, boxes are serial tagged.

I want to produce the sequence count based on box_sn as result in the picture.

I wish pandas dataframe solution or and excel formula. can any experts give me a hints to solve this?
thank you.

[image]

edited:
i am able to generate the sequence number based on single catergories as in picture below.
with formula : G2 = IF(B2<>B1,G1+1,G1)
this will continue sequence the box_sn, but i want machine B box_sn restart the sequence.
[image]

edited 2:
this is final result of my temp_reading. thank you very much.
[image]

Comment: Could this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36652577/5276797

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: i actually asking for suggestion in algorithm than coding style. excel formula is okie and i able to translate in code or load the calculated file into dataframe. thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @IanS, thanks for the link, it helps me in trying pandas series method to build the dataframe again. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, an Excel solution would be (entered in column F):

```
=IF(A2<>A1,1,IF(B2=B1,F1,F1+1))
```

Comment: why not directly start with 1 for row 1 and then (row 2 downwards) `=F1*(A2=A3)+(B2=B3)`?

Comment: @DirkReichel in which cell? F2?

Comment: oh... wait... row 1 are headers... `=F2*(A3=A4)+(B3=B4)` starting from `F3` and in `F2` directly enter `1` :P

Answer (score 2):

With pandas:

**First**, create the data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'machine': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
        'box_sn': ['A3','A3','A5','A5','B1','B1','B2','B2','B3','B3'],
        'item_sn': ['i1','i2','i3','i4','i1','i2','i3','i4','i5','i6']
    })
```

**Second**, work with a single machine (here `B`):

```
dfB = df[df.machine == 'B']
(dfB['box_sn'].shift() != dfB['box_sn']).cumsum()
```

The `cumsum` increments each time the box serial number changes - which is what you want. (This is assuming the serial numbers are ordered, otherwise you can use `sort_values`.)

**Third**, apply the above to the entire dataframe via `groupby`:

```
def sequence(df1):
    return (df1['box_sn'].shift() != df1['box_sn']).cumsum()
df_sequence = df.groupby('machine').apply(sequence)
```

This is the output (we're almost there):

```
In [17]: df_sequence
Out[17]: 
machine   
A        0    1
         1    1
         2    2
         3    2
B        4    1
         5    1
         6    2
         7    2
         8    3
         9    3
```

**Fourth**, we need to drop the first level of the index (`A`, `B`) before we include the result in the original dataframe:

```
df_sequence.index = df_sequence.index.droplevel(0)
df['sequence'] = df_sequence
```

Comment: I spent almost an hour yesterday to find a Pandas solution with no luck. I miss spreadsheets sometimes. :)

Comment: very intuitive, i actually testing it since last night. i was working on multiple categories, for example not only machine, but machine and factory, machine, factory, country

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like, after reading your data using

```
df = pd.read_excel(path)
```

you could do:

```
df.groupby('box_sn').size()
```

IIUC and your goal is to get the number of items per `box_sn`?

Comment: my goal is to plot a heatmap like shmoo plot on temp_reading. regardless of box_sn, i want to align box by it sequence. a new columns of sequence is help in the plotting.

Comment: df.groupby('box_sn').size() to me is counting the items_sn. i need to individual value of the temp_reading

Comment: @pinky are you still interested in a pandas solution?

Comment: @IanS , the answer is yes. i am still trying how to manipulate the dataframe to generate the seq columns. any hints? ^.^